# How do I add strings together with different names

Tags: java, string

I've already created the ticketAgent and ticketType class and I'm having a tough time trying to add the strings. I've tried using a wrapper class but not sure if that's even the right approach.  I've pasted my code and then the prompt respectively.  Thanks for the help. I'm a first time poster, so I hope I've followed the posting guidelines.

Prompt:

Write a program called TicketBooth that instantiates at 3 different ticket agents.  The TicketBooth program should prompt the user for the ticket agent they wish to purchase a ticket from and then display the list of ticket types and prices that are available.  The TicketBooth program should allow the user to make a selection for the ticket to purchase.  After a ticket type is selected, the TicketBooth program should display the:

•   total sales for that ticket agent
•   total number of tickets sold by the ticket agent
•   total number of tickets sold by all ticket agents

The TicketBooth program should continue to prompt the user to purchase tickets from one of the ticket agents until the user types quit.

```
 package Exercises;
    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class TicketBooth {

        private static Scanner input;

        public static void main(String[] args) {

            input = new Scanner(System.in);

                String ticketAgent = "sam", "nicole" , "alex";
                String ticketType = "one";
                int t = Integer.parseInt(ticketAgent);
                int s = Integer.parseInt(ticketType);
                int sum;

                System.out.println("Please select your ticket agent: ");
                ticketAgent = input.next();

                System.out.println("Please select your ticket type or press -1 to quit: ");
                ticketType = input.next();  

                sum = t +s;
                System.out.println("The total tickets that were sold were: " + sum);



        }
    }






package exercises;

public class TicketAgent {

private static int numOfTicksPerAgent;

    private String agentName;
    private int numSold = 0;
    private double totalSales = 0.0;

    public TicketAgent(String agent) {
        agentName = agent;

        numSold = 0;
        totalSales = 0.0;
        numOfTicksPerAgent += 1;
    }

    public void sellTicket(TicketType tt) {
        numSold++;
        totalSales = totalSales + tt.getticketPrice();
        numOfTicksPerAgent++;
    }

    public double gettotalSales() {
        return totalSales;
    }

    public double getnumSold() {
        return numSold;
    }

    public double getnumOfTicksPerAgent() {
        return numOfTicksPerAgent;

    }
}








package exercises;




public enum TicketType 
{
    CHILD (6.50),
    ADULT (9.50),
    SENIOR (6.50);

private double tikPrice;
TicketType(double price) 
{
    tikPrice = price;
}
public double getticketPrice()
{   
return tikPrice;

    }
}
```

Comment: How is "sam" or "nicole" a reasonable integer? (And I'm pretty sure alex is a float.)

Comment: Where are your `TicketAgent` and `TicketType` classes? Or are you referring to your (broken) `ticketAgent` and `ticketType` String instances?

Comment: @DaveNewton I am fairly sure "one" is an integer, but not in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that it seems that this is your homework and
nobody wants to make your homeworks for you.

*edit: I saw that you added your classes just now. 
All you have to do is to add the do while loop 
and instantiate your Agents in the right way.
Where, exactly, is your problem? So we can help you better.*

My first approach would be, to make it simple, 
to write a TicketAgent **class** and a TicketType **class**.

Write the TicketAgent in a way, you can put the name of 
the agent and the types into the **constructor**.

```
TicketAgent agentSam = new TicketAgent("Sam", new ExpensiveTicket());
```

Add setter and getter **methods**.

And the TicketType needs a **float** value for the price and maybe a **String** description
or something like that.

After you are done with this, go back to your main class.
Open a **do while loop** and set as the loop argument a **boolean**
value for the user abort, which is false at the beginning and
changes if the user types in the quit command.

Before the loop, instantiate the Agents with the tickets.

Display names and prices. Display tickets. Count together. Ask for abort.

Hope this helps a little.
And sorry for my english, it is not my mother-tongue.

```
    additional:



private boolean userWantsToQuit = false;
private List<TicketAgent> avaibleAgents = new ArrayList<TicketAgent>();
private List<TicketAgent> usedAgents= new ArrayList<TicketAgent>();
private List<TickeType> boughtTickets= new ArrayList<TicketType>();

main(...){

   agents.add(new TicketAgent("Sam"));
   agents.add(new TicketAgent("wise"));
   agents.add(new TicketAgent("gamgee"));

   do{

   usedAgents.add(askUserForAgent()); //extra static method
   boughtTickets.add(askUserForType(agent)); //extra static method
   userWantsToQuit = askUserToQuit();//extra static method
   }while(!userWantsToQuit);

   displayAgentSummary(usedAgents);
   displayTicketSummary(boughtTickets);
}

[...]

public static displayAgentSummary(List<TicketAgent> agents)
{
    for(TicketAgent agent : agents)
    {
       System.out.println("Served by: " + agent.getName());
    }
}

public static displayTicketSummary(List<TicketType> tickets)
{
    float totalPrice = 0;
    for(TicketType ticket : tickets)
    {
       totalPrice =+ ticket.getPrice();
       System.out.println("You bought a " + ticket.getName() + " for " + ticket.getPrice()";
    }
    System.out.println("You bought tickets in total for " + totalPrice + " dollar".
}
```